# Is there anything wrong with this implementation of sleep?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

For a long time I've been using the following function to make current thread sleep for some time:

```
class Utils {

static public sleep(int ms) {
  try {
     Thread.sleep(ms);
  } catch(InterruptedException x) {}
}

}
```

But since I'm siliently ignore the exception I wonder if there can be situations this function will become evil?

Comment: On interrupt, thread will awake prematurely and you will ignore it.

Comment: whats the point of handling an exception when you dont have a message log ??

Comment: Do you care if the sleep is interrupted prematurely? If not, place a comment in the catch block (between the {}) to explain it. If you do care, then deal with it. It could become evil if you are doing a massive number of loops and the sleep was to slow down the processing and for some reason the sleep doesn't work (e.g. is constantly interrupted) for some reason. Probably an unlikely case.

Answer (score 7):

If you're not using interrupts in your own code, you should keep the interrupt state with:

```
catch(InterruptedException x) {
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
}
```

or you can deal with it higher up by throwing `InterruptedException`. This immediately lets callers know there's an interrupt, otherwise it can be checked sometime later with isInterrupted().

If you must sleep for the full time, then you can continue sleeping after the interrupt, and reinterrupt the thread afterwards. See guava's `Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly` for an implementation of this.

By not clearing the interrupt status of the thread, you're preventing your code from interfering with anything else that might be using interrupts. So if in the future you want to interrupt a thread, you don't have obscure bugs where sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't.

If you will never use interrupts, it might be possible to completely ignore it, but it's nice to keep the flexibility just in case.

Comment: Interesting, what is that good for? We ignored that Exception, too.

Comment: @AlexWien Catching and reinterrupting is the same as the original code, but without removing the interrupt - the thread remains interrupted and can be handled later. I've added more information on other possibilities too but what to choose depends context.